# Prestashop signle translation to multiple forms

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

There is one input to translate "%d products". However, in Slovak language there are two forms of this translation. The following pseudocode shows the desired translation:

```
"%d products" = (%d < 5) ? "%d produkty" : "%d produktov";
```

Is it possible to make single translation varying by %d parameter in the Prestashops back office translations?

Comment: No it's not possible. You'll have to bring that logic in template files

Comment: Thank you @FlorianLemaitre!